# How do I prevent mail width compressing in the gmail?

Tags: email, gmail, html-email

I have a mail with fixed width. But gmail compresses it. How to prevent the compression?

```html
<table bgcolor="#F3F3F3"
       style="Margin:0;margin:0;padding: 0;font-family:'Arial',sans-serif;max-width:100%;padding:0;width:100%;background:#F3F3F3;">
  <style>
    a{
      text-decoration: none;
      color: inherit;
      color: inherit !important;
    }
    @media print{
      body, html{
        -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
      }
    }
  </style>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <center>
        <table width="600" bgcolor="#6999CC"
               style="Margin:0 auto;margin:0 auto;max-width:100%;width:600px;background:#6999cc;">
          <tbody bgcolor="#6999CC" style="background: #6999CC">
          <tr bgcolor="#6999CC" style="background: #6999CC">
            <td bgcolor="#6999CC" style="background: #6999CC">
              <center bgcolor="#6999CC" style="background: #6999CC">
                <table>
                  <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td height="4" style="height: 4px;line-height: 4px;">&nbsp;</td>
                  </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
                <!--spacer-->

                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="570" ...
```

In other apps I have no this problem. I have tried to fix all layers, wrapper should be 100% width. Is there any trick to  make gmail to understand the width?

If I have several letters gmail makes "conversation", and all content makes as quotes. And after it every quote layout brakes!!! Even if it was ok earlier.Because gmail cuts half of styles using this "great" function!

Comment: Gmail expects your style tag to be in the head of the document. Gmail will read only the first media query. HTML + images combined should be less than 102kb. That should get you started

Comment: @Syfer what should I write, if I want to save my 600px width always?

Comment: You are asking about two things. One is conversation view and the other email squashing(?). For conversation, send emails to Gmail with a different subject line each time with different body copy that should fix it. As for squashing there was a question already asked before https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35479271/force-inbox-by-gmail-to-render-desktop-version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is because of increasing font-size in the app. To prevent increasing I have add this line in the end:

```html
<div style="white-space:nowrap!important;line-height: 0; color: #ffffff;">
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -  - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
</div>
```